# How can I mix Boolean and Object Mode in vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

how can I mix Boolean and Object Mode in my Vue Router?:

```
props: true
```

with

```
props: { someRouteSpecificProps: "someValue"}
```

I need to also send props via `router.push`.
So:

```
//router
 {
      path: "somePath",
      name: "someName",
      props: { someRouteSpecificProps: "someSpecificValue" },
      component: successAndLogoutPage,
 },

//component
this.$router.push({
   name: "someName",
   query: this.$route.query,
   params: {
        ValueOnlyKnownInCompoent: 500000,
        AnotherValueOnlyKnownInCompoent: "foo",
   }
},
```

Using Vue 2, Js not ts.
Doing as I did, will ignore the props from the component. Doing props: true will use the props from the component but I still neet the someRouteSpecificProps directly in the router definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using the function mode:

```
props: (route) => {
    return { someSpecificProps: 'value here', ...route.params };
},
```

In route the params are provided and can be provided to the props.

(Credit to @PerpetualWar from the vue discord, on whos advice the solution was formed)